# How can i add a new project to my existing already project and create a dll file from the new project?

Tags: c#

I already added a new project to my project in the new project I just created a new class and copied a code to the new class a code which I want to use in the other project.
The new project is also a Windows Forms type.

What I want is to create a dll from the new project class so I can later use the dll in the other project to use the class in the dll from the new project I just added.

So in the new added project I changed in the project properties>application>Output Type>Class Library
But now when I'm trying to add the reference of the new project class I can't find any dll file in the new project under bin>Debug directory.

Again I have one project which I added a new project to it's solution.
The new project is also a windows forms type without any code but only one added class which there I added some code.
What I want to do is to create a dll of the new project so I can use the class later with the main project.

But why it didn't create any dll?

Comment: The problem im facing now is that in the new project i just added type of class library and then added the code from the class in the main project i need ot use some code from my main project. So i created a dll file out of my main project and added it to the new project but then im getting many conflict warnings between the new project class events and the dll of the main project i added wich also have the same class code and events. So there is confilcts but i need somehow to use the code/s from the main project if not im getting errors on the new project class about many Usings...

Comment: I mean in my new project where i copied the code from the class i have in the main project this class have events im using in Form1 in my main project. But since i need in this class to use some things from my main project namespace there is a confilcts.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the same code defined in both projects?  You definitely don't want that.  For one thing, it's a violation of the DRY principle.  ("Don't Repeat Yourself")  It also leads to errors like what you're seeing.  It may be "the same class" in the sense that it has the same code, but it compiles as two different classes with the same name.  So the code using it won't be able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: The "application context" project (in this case a Windows Forms project) should reference the "portable library" project (in this case a Class Library project).  Never the other way around.  Code that's portable should go in the class library and be used by the application.

Comment: The reason im trying to do it is that i need this class to be once compiled as target x64 and once as target x86 and then in the main project to select if it's X using this dll if it's Y use the other one. So i thought to make for that two projects. But im getting conflicts. So maybe i need to not using the class in my main project and just call when i need this class each time to the other dll(each new project ?) ?

Comment: Ok, the x86 vs. 64 part merits its own question, because that was definitely not obvious as part of this question.  And I'm guessing there's a much better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to accomplish.  (Can't you target both in a single compilation?  Why do you need to select between two different DLLs which both contain the same code?  Explain in a new question.)  Either way, duplicating code is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be that maybe you didn't compile it yet?

However, there's a better answer.  If I understand you correctly, you have this:

```
Solution 1
  -- Windows Forms Project A
  -- Windows Forms Project B
```

And there is code in `Windows Forms Project B` which needs to be accessed by `Windows Forms Project A`.  You took a step in the right direction here:

> So in the new added project i changed in the project properties>application>Output Type>Class Library

You might want to take an extra step to clean that up, though.  Because now your `Class Library Project B` is still referencing Windows Forms libraries that it doesn't need.  In fact, it very much *shouldn't* reference Windows Forms libraries or any other UI libraries.  In order to be portable, the Class Library should be entirely UI-independent.  (As a tip, if you ever find yourself needing to reference a UI library from a portable Class Library then you probably made a mistake somewhere and should re-think what logic belongs where.)

So, for starters, create a brand new Class Library project so that you have this:

```
Solution 1
  -- Windows Forms Project A
  -- Class Library Project B
```

Next, you need `Project A` to reference `Project B`.  You're trying to do this by referencing the output DLL, but this isn't the right approach unless you have a *very* good reason to do this.  Instead, since they're in the same Solution you can use a [Project Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx).

If you're using Visual Studio, right click on `Project A` and select `Add Reference`.  Depending on the version of Visual Studio, the layout will be different.  But what you want to add is a Project Reference to another Project in the Solution.  Select `Project B` and you're all set.

At this point, you don't need to worry about the compilation of `Project B` independently.  It's merely a component referenced by `Project A`.  When you compile `Project A`, a DLL for `Project B` will be in the compiled output by default.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** If you're not finding the DLL it's probably because it hasn't been built yet. Besides, explicitly adding the DLL when the 2 projects are in the same solution probably isn't what you want to do anyway.

**Continuing with my original post:**
Instead of browsing for the DLL, click on the "Projects" tab on the "Add Reference" dialog and it will add the reference from there.

Comment: It accomplishes what he said he wanted to do -> reference the project he set as a "class library" from the first project. However, David took more time and gave a more verbose and more helpful answer and I've +1'd his.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new project to your solution, you need to specify a Class Library, not a Windows Forms Application. Once that is done, you will be able to add a Reference to your first project, and the second project (the library) should be an option in one of the tabs (possibly "Projects" or "Solution" depending on your version). The DLL will not show up until you actually build the Class Library project.